# Servlets - Send Response Based on Session Only

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I get a request from one client, I want to build a response and send it to two clients (one of which is the requester). The only piece of information I know about the other client is its session. Is there a way to construct a `HttpResponse` object using an `HttpSession` object?

Comment: Please take some time and rewrite your question. It's impossible to understand what you want to accomplish, what you have tried and what you have read already.

Comment: But you need to send a response for the client to have something to read. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about what youre trying to accomplish, but you may want to contact the second client via "reversal ajax". You may want to take a look at [Comet Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

> Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it. **Wikipedia**